# How to Change color of " * " in placeholder

Tags: html, css

HTML Code

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Name *" >
```

Comment: Or if you prefer using only CSS, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655493/how-can-i-style-individual-parts-of-an-input-placeholder

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699705/is-there-any-way-to-change-one-word-color-of-placeholder