# Add CSS to the part of place holder

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

Can I apply css to the part of place holder in text box ?

```
<input name="name" placeholder= "Enter my name"> </input>
```

can I change the color of `name` in to red.
But  I want to apply color only to the specific word only.

Comment: have to wrap only that word with tgs you an apply css to

Comment: You have your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655493/how-can-i-style-individual-parts-of-an-input-placeholder).. Good luck

Comment: cannot apply tags to place holder

Comment: AH, well you cant then.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
<input id="name" name="name" placeholder= "Enter my name"> </input>

//chrome, opera, safari
#name::-webkit-input-placeholder:after {
   content:"name";
   color:red;
}

//mozilla firefox
#name::-moz-placeholder:after {
    content:"name";
    color:red;
}

//internet explorer
#name:-ms-input-placeholder:after {     
    content:"name";
    color:red;
}
```