# Is it possible to have multiple text styling for an Input element's placeholder?

Tags: html, css, sass

I was wondering if there is any pure HTML/CSS way to create a placeholder like the attached one, which combines both **bold** and regular stylings inside the *placeholder*.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I style individual parts of an input placeholder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655493/how-can-i-style-individual-parts-of-an-input-placeholder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no pure CSS solution for that (maybe combine `::first-letter` and `::placeholder`?) but here is the Solution of [PressTigers](https://www.presstigers.com/styling-placeholder-text-of-an-input-field-with-multiple-colors/):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.input-required input').on('focus',function(){
  if(!$(this).parent('.input-required').find('label').hasClass('hide')){
                        $(this).parent('.input-required').find('label').addClass('hide');
                        }
 });
            $('.input-required input').on('blur',function(){
  if($(this).val() == '' && $(this).parent('.input-required').find('label').hasClass('hide')){
                        $(this).parent('.input-required').find('label').removeClass('hide');
                    }
             });
});
```

```css
.input-required {
  position: relative;
}
.input-required > label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -0.6em 0 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.input-required .hide {
  display: none;
}
.first-letter {
  color: #6b6b6b;
}
.second-letter {
  color: red;
}
.third-letter {
  color: black;
}
.fourth-letter {
  color: blue;
}
.fifth-letter {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-required">
 <label>
             <span class="first-letter">Password</span>  
                        <span class="second-letter">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="input-text">
 </div>
<div class="input-required">
 <label>
             <span class="first-letter">H</span>  
                        <span class="second-letter">e</span>
                        <span class="third-letter">l</span>
                        <span class="fourth-letter">l</span>
                        <span class="fifth-letter">o</span>
             </label>
 <input type="text" id="hello" name="Hello" class="input-text">
</div>
```

---

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking for something which possibly could involved the placeholder pseudo element or something like that which I am thinking now might be impossible!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to simulate a fake placeholder, adding an extra element inside a parent container of your `input`, then use css to position it where the placeholder should be and use javascript to make it "dissapear" when the user starts writing in the input.

I made a pen of how it should be made: [fake placeholder](https://codepen.io/2alin/pen/ePxXWv).

Let me know any doubts you get.